# how to search for regular expression in C++, then process, then replace

Tags: c++, regex, replace

C++11 provides regex_search and regex_replace, but I wish to find patterns bracketed by a set of tags, then based on those tags do further processing beyond what regex can do.

For example:

```
$mch(2,4,5,7$
$img(filename.jpg$
$vid(filename.mp4$
$mat3,4(2,4,6,1,2,3,4,5,1$
```

Recognizing the tags is easy:

```
regex r(R"(\$.*\()(.*\$)";
```

the problem is to search, then apply the code, then replace the search. The most elegant solution I came up with is:

```
if (regex_searcH(line, m, r)) {
  if (m[1] == "$mch") {

  } else if (m[1] == "$img") {
    buildString(replace, "<img src='", m[1], "'/>");
  }
}
```

and then

```
line.replace(m.position(0), m.length(0), replace);
```

Comment: Do you have to use regular expressions to parse the text?  Can you use a grammar & parser like [Boost Spirit x3](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/index.html)?

Comment: In C++, it is much easier to use 3 different regex replace calls here.

Comment: Are you sure that your regex are correct? Or, better said: Can you explain in words, what you are looking for?

Comment: @eljay I really like the link for Spirit x3 so thank you. Not sure I want another project, but that does look awesome.

Comment: You're welcome!  Spirit x3 is powerful, expressive, performant.  It's an "all in C++" solution (rather than using tools, e.g. Flex and Bison).  Downsides is that Spirit x3 uses (abuses?) really mind-bending C++ operator overloads to express the grammar.  Its a big hammer, which may be overkill for tiny grammars -- unless the programmer is already familiar with Spirit x3 and has paid the barrier learning curve cost.